# How to perform sql queries in jpa repository based on String parameter

Tags: spring-boot

I want to display table data based on different parameters like price range as well as category.

```java
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Double price;
    private String category;

public Item() {
    super();
}
Item(String name, String category){
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.category = category;
}

public Item(Long id, String name,Double price,String category) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.category=category;
}
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long >{



}
```

I want to use postman to display table data based on category and price range.
Due to the usage of long as a parameter, I am only able to retrieve item based on id number.

Answer (score 1):

From your question what i understood was that you need to have methods to return data based on Category and Price rather than using the id.

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long >{

List<Item> findByCategory(String category);
List<Item> findByPrice(Double price);

}
```

You can use the Spring JPA Query methods to have default implementations for that as well.

For more information read [Official Doc](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/).

### Another Example:

```
 List<Item> findByCategoryAndPrice(String category,Double price);
```